# AngularFirestore snapshotChanges() weird behavior

Tags: angular, firebase, rxjs, angularfire

I'm trying to do a very simple CRUD operation with Angularfire and Firebase Realtime Database. Here's what my Angular service is doing:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FirestoreService {

  constructor(private db: AngularFirestore) { }

  public getUser(userid: string) {
    return this.db.collection('users').doc(userid).valueChanges();
  }
}
```

I am trying to use it in the following way. In this snippet `this.userid` is a public global `Subject<string>`. I've checked, it supplies the correct user ID in the following snippet.

```
      this.userid.pipe(filter(x => !!x))
        .subscribe(userid => {

          this.firestoreService.getUser(userid)
            .subscribe(result => {
              console.log(result);
            });

        });
```

Contrary to expectations, the console output is not a nice clean JSON of the requested document (which exists) but a massive hot mess of raw JSON data.

[image: From Developer Tools]

There are two weird things about this.

1. If I change `snapshotChanges()` to `valueChanges()`, the result is the data I expected.
2. If I move the subscription outside of the `userid` subscription, the result is correct again.
3. But here's the weirdest of all. If I duplicate the subscription...

```
      this.userid.pipe(filter(x => !!x))
        .subscribe(userid => {

          this.firestoreService.getUser(userid)
            .subscribe(result => {
              console.log('----[ DATABASE RESULT ]----');
              console.log(result);
            });

          this.firestoreService.getUser(userid)
            .subscribe(result => {
              console.log('----[ DATABASE RESULT 2 ]----');
              console.log(result);
            });
        })
```

... then BOTH ones will return the correct database result, and not that big weird JSON.

Ideas, suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 0):

All right, it was obviously I who didn't catch the difference between `snapshotChanges()` and `valueChanges()`. Apparently only the latter returns the document itself while the former brings a lot of metadata with it, hence the "hot mess of JSON".

The best way to get data only once is to subscribe to `valueChanges()` and immediately unsubscribing.